# DDEV: Vanilla WordPress config creates port 80 conflict between web and dba containers

Tags: ddev

Following [these](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/quickstart/#wordpress) simple instructions I've created a vanilla WordPress installation of DDEV. However, when I try to start it, I get the error `Failed to start MYSITE: Unable to listen on required ports, port 80 is already in use`.

Running `docker ps` I can see that the `dba` container created by DDEV is the conflict. (I have no other non-DDEV containers or programs trying to use 80.)

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                           COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                    PORTS                                                         NAMES
f198f9a79670   drud/ddev-webserver:v1.21.5-MYSITE-built               "/start.sh"              19 seconds ago   Up 13 seconds (healthy)   8025/tcp, 127.0.0.1:61855->80/tcp, 127.0.0.1:61854->443/tcp   ddev-MYSITE-web
512c39953fa7   drud/ddev-dbserver-mariadb-10.4:v1.21.5-MYSITE-built   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   19 seconds ago   Up 13 seconds (healthy)   127.0.0.1:61851->3306/tcp                                     ddev-MYSITE-db
e16ab3b8c611   phpmyadmin:5                                                    "/docker-entrypoint.…"   20 seconds ago   Up 13 seconds             80/tcp                                                        ddev-MYSITE-dba
```

I've tried changing `phpmyadmin_port` and `phpmyadmin_https_port` in `.ddev/config.yaml`, but those only change the internal port, not the port its mapped to. You can see this in `.ddev/.ddev-docker-compose-full.yaml`:

```
dba:
    container_name: ddev-MYSITE-dba
    environment:
        HTTP_EXPOSE: 8036:80
        HTTPS_EXPOSE: 8037:80
...
web:
    container_name: ddev-MYSITE-web
    environment:
        HTTP_EXPOSE: 80:80,8025:8025
        HTTPS_EXPOSE: 443:80,8026:8025
```

How can I get the `dba` and `web` containers created by DDEV to not conflict with eachother?

Answer (score 1):

As the message says, your port 80 is already in use by some other application. And the error message gives you a link to the [documentation on this problem](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/usage/troubleshooting/#web-server-ports-already-occupied)

The DDEV docs give extensive instructions on how to resolve this. Please go through the docs and find out what's conflicting. It's often Apache, but you don't say what OS you're on so I can't guess.

Comment: As stated, no other programs are using port 80. I'm on Windows 10 Pro using Docker Desktop over WSL2. Running `netstat -aon | findstr :80` shows no PIDs with an ESTABLISHED connection to port 80. I can also start and stop other non-DDEV projects with docker compose that successfully connect to port 80.

Comment: On WSL2 you have to look both inside the WSL2 distro and also on the Windows side. Are you using WSL2? The problem is not things that have established connections, you're looking for things that are listening.

Comment: The problem was inside my WSL2 distro, not Windows. For whatever reason, apache was running there. Thanks!